# I want to open launcher or android application on click of link in browser

Tags: android

I have tried many solution to open application on click of link in browser but nothing is work for me.
I have already tried like this solution.

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/someresource/"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/someresource/"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: be some more specific about your question provide details

Comment: whats your deep link?

Comment: Read for DeepLink here https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 0):

```
try this its working code.
    <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                    <data
                        android:host="qa.mintshowapp.com"
                        android:pathPrefix="/m/showroom/mintdetaillanding"
                        android:scheme="http" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is not working.
please check my code.   <activity android:name=".Activity.Joinhubactivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/m/showroom/mintdetaillanding"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: its working code bro, i think you missing something.

Comment: yeah it should work.but it is not working in my case.
 i am trying to find whats the exact problem in my code.
I have not touched intent filter with main launcher.
and I am trying to access it via www.example.com in chrome

Comment: can you share your actual host url?

Comment: currently I am trying with www.example.com only

Comment: I have tried my all but no solution is working. Can you share me any working demo? Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: This code is working on url click on page. but i am looking for same  solution , When i type url and click ok buttton than my application need to launch.